# Get all entries from a channel

Tags: plugin-development

Is there any known way to get all the entries from a certain channel? I dont want to do this in a view but in PHP since i need to do a bulk update of an attribute to all the entries in a certain channel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would do that using an ElementCriteriaModel:

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'mySectionHandle';
$criteria->limit = null;

$entries = $criteria->find();
```

You can read all about how to work with ElementCriteriaModel’s in the [Working with Elements](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) guide in the Craft docs.